# Displaying Sum of Each Element in Firestore (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this this collection in Firestore where each document has 'count' property, and it is int of 1. I would want to have a function that adds that count property of 1 to total property somewhere in Firebase, I presume it would be another collection that would just calculate the sum as they are added 1 by 1. I'm at a bit of a loss how I would go around doing that.

The collection is displayed in a regular Stream and each element is in a List Tile. So what I'm after is to get a function that would be called somewhere that would add that '1' to the let's say collection called 'Total' and it would calculate whenever that function is executed and add that 1 to total. Also, how would I display that 'Total' collection somewhere else on another page as a string perhaps?

I attached a general image how my Firestore looks like just to give you guys a general picture.
[image]

I don't think code is necessary here, since as I said, it is just a regular List Tile and Stream of the 'Names' collection, but let me know if you need more context. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cloud Firestore in order to increase an integer property, you would need first to iterate through the documents, by [reading stored data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and subsequently perform an [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) to change the value of this specific field in the corresponding "Total" collection.

To display the collection using flutter, you can take a look at [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) which can listen to the document changes and display appropriately, I also found [this Medium article](https://medium.com/quick-code/reading-lists-from-firestore-using-streambuilder-in-flutter-eda590f461ed) which might help.

Comment: It seems pretty costly to iterate through each element, in terms of reads, so I might pass this one if that's the only solution to this. I heard there is the 'increment' option, but I am not sure how to use it in this case, and if it's applicable.

Comment: I understand your concerns, also regarding the increment, I found [this official](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) and [this (not Google)](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-increment-tips/#:~:text=Increment%20is%20a%20special%20value,does%20all%20the%20calculation%20serverside.) documentation